# How to add a property to `change` event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a `<select>` box:

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option value="1">one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
   <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

I need to modify it's `change` event, so it would have a `val_after_change` property, no matter how event was triggered.

```
// THIS FUNCTION CANNOT BE MODIFIED
$('#myselect').change(function(e){
    // this should alert select value after change
    alert(e.val); 
});
```

I know, that here I could just `alert $(this).val()`, but my real example is more complex and need `e.val`. I know this works in [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), but I could not understand their source code.

How do I modify the event? Do I need to make a wrapper or something? Any help would be appriciated.

**Edit:**

I'm making a wrapper on a library, that makes `selects` use `e.val` property, so I cannot modify the `change` event itself. I need the property **to be there already** when event is triggered. Something like this, but make it a default behavour:

```
e = jQuery.Event('change', {val: 2});
$('#myselect').trigger(e);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHfrb/)

Comment: What makes it so much more complex that $(this).val() doesn't work?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, I'm making a wrapper around "select2". It's `change` events expect to have `val` property

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur I got it, here is a shot at it :

```
(function ($){
   // keep a copy of the original "select2" function
   var lib_select2 = $.fn.select2;

   // wrap it into a call which 
   // first adds a listener to add the value as a property of the event,
   // then adds whatever extra stuff the library adds
   $.fn.select2 = function(){
        this.change(function(e){
            e.val = this.value;
        });

        lib_select2.apply(this, arguments);
   }
})(jQuery)
```